# Is there any way to comment in tsx typescript codes without curly braces?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, comments, tsx, react-tsx

When I comment something in my react tsx file, it usually wrapped between { } automatically, even if it is in single line, and it may be mixed up by other parts of codes.

Is there any way to comment in tsx typescript codes without curly braces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to your question: no, it is not possible.

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-build.html#how-can-i-write-comments-in-jsx